# Nginx - Primary script unknown while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, webserver, lumen, nginx-config

Recently we have migrated from `Apache2` to `Nginx` server. Consider we have domain `www.test.com` and following is the `www.test.com.conf` and I had disabled `default` Nginx default file.

```
server {
    server_name www.test.com;

    # Character Set
    charset utf-8;

    # Logs
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # Directory Indexes
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Document Root
    root /var/www/html/project1/public;

    # Location
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Error Pages
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    # PHP-FPM Support
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; #/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Block access to .htaccess
    location ~ \.htaccess {
        deny all;
    }
    client_body_timeout 10s;
    client_header_timeout 10s;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.test.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.test.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.test.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen *:80;
    server_name www.test.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

With the above configuration, I can access `https://www.test.com` without issues. In this case root `/var/www/html/project1/public`. Now to access multiple applications from the same domain I had changed the root directive to `/var/www/html/` and tried to access `https://www.test.com/project1/public` but I'm getting the following error

`FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream`

May I know the reason for this issue? my application is `Lumen` which is a mirco service framework by `Laravel`.

Comment: Your `try_files` statement is specifying `/index.php` which should presumably be changed to whichever project you want as default (e.g. `/project1/public/index.php`).

Comment: @RichardSmith It worked for me, what if I've multiple projects like `project1`, `project2` and request to relevent project based on urls like `https://www.test.com/project1/public` and `https://www.test.com/project2/`?

Comment: Use separate `location` blocks for each project, with a `try_files` statement containing the appropriate default URI.

Answer (score 1):

By changing the following blocks it is working for me

from `root /var/www/html/project1/public;` to `root /var/www/html;`

And we need to add multiple `location` blocks based on the requirement. Consider I want to access two `Lumen/ Laravel` applications from single domain, then I need to add two `location` blocks as

```
location /project1/public {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /project1/public/index.php$is_args$args;
}
location /project2/public {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /project2/public/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Credits go to [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith)

Comment: I have never seen this problem before, but this was the solution. Thank you ! 
to debug : (/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf) add ```
m.max_children = 1
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 1```

get the running pid : ```ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep php``` then ```strace -p 6711```